# How to unbundle a git bundle into my already existing but empty repository?

Tags: git

I have an empty git repository and I have a bundle, I must unbundle it into my already existing repository. It don't work, I don't understand.

Comment: Why do you need the empty repository? Unbundling will create a repo like when you clone.

Comment: The goal is to put the bundle' data into my empty github repository. If I clone the bundle, I will have two repository with no data in my github repo ?

Comment: If your empty github repo is already created, unbundle locally, add the reference to your github as a remote (`git remote add`), and push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd repo
git pull /path/to/bundle master
```